# undefined on lottie components

Tags: next.js, lottie

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Stories from 'stories-react';
import 'stories-react/dist/index.css';
import Lottie from "lottie-react";

const Slide = () => {
  const animationURL = 'public/background-lottie-v3.json';
  return (
    <div>
      <Lottie
        animationData={animationURL}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default function Home() {
  const stories = [
    {
      type: 'component',
      component: Slide,
      duration: 15000,
    }
  ];
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Stories width="393.75px" height="700px" stories={stories} />
    </>
  )
}
```

I'm using nextjs for a project and when importing a lottie animation inside a component it gets set to undefined and breaks. here is my code

how can i solve this?